# Function still catches errors from other functions after returning data using a callback

Tags: javascript

Fairly new to javascript. I call a function and send some data. The function returns data with a callback. I then send data to a different function that contains an error. Somehow, the error is caught in the CATCH block of the first function. I thought the first function was finished after the callback. I don't understand how the error gets back to the CATCH block of the first function.

```js
var data1 = 1;
let myMessage = document.querySelector('.fiddleMessage');
myMessage.value = '';

//Main function
function myFunc1(myData, callback) {
  myMessage.innerHTML = 'myFunc1 - enter Try block';
  try {
    myData += 1;
    myMessage.innerHTML += '<br>myFunc1 - myData = ' + myData;

    //Callback to send results   
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
      myMessage.innerHTML += '<br>myFunc1 - return data with callback';
      return (callback(myData));
      //This next message should not be reachable
      myMessage.innerHTML += '<br>myFunc1 - after callback';
    }

  } catch (err) {
    myMessage.innerHTML += '<br>myFunc1 - in CATCH block';
    myMessage.innerHTML += '<br>' + err;
    console.log('myFunc1 - in CATCH block');
    console.log(err);

    //Send a message back to calling function
    if (err) {
      if (typeof callback === "function") {
        myMessage.innerHTML += '<br>myFunc1 - in catch block - in callback';
        var errorMessage = "dataError";
        callback(errorMessage);
      }
    }
  }
}


//Function to do some processing
function myFunc2(myData2) {
  myMessage.innerHTML += '<br>myFunc2 - myData2 = ' + myData2;

  //Cause an error here with the wrong name
  //In the following line, "result" should be "myData2"
  //The error will be sent back to myFunc1 to the CATCH block - why?
  myMessage.innerHTML += '<br>myFunc2 - cause ERROR here';
  var data3 = myResult += 1;
  //var data3 = myData2 += 1;
  return data3;
}

//Call myFunc1
myFunc1(data1, function(result) {
  myMessage.innerHTML += '<br>call to myFunc1 - result = ' + result;
  if (result === "dataError") {
    myMessage.innerHTML += '<br>call to myFunc1 - received a dataError';

  } else {
    myMessage.innerHTML += '<br>call to myFunc1 - make a call to myFunc2';
    var data2 = myFunc2(result);
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<h1>Function exit Callback</h1>

<p>This test is to demonstrate a function does not close after a callback. Send data to a function, the callback returns the data, then send to a different function with an error and the error is caught in the CATCH block of the first function</p><br>

<div class="fiddleMessage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may seem strange to you, but the last function to end in your code is your first called function `myFunc1`.

Your callback has little or no sense because you're not executing any asynchronous code. (In the case of asynchronous code, the callback could be fired after the main function has finished processing).

When the JavaScript engine runs into an error, it goes up the current stack until it finds an error handler (in this case, it is in the first called function). If an error handler is not found, error will propagate to window object (you'll see it in the console an it will probably break your code).

Also, you are calling the callback function passing it a value and you are expecting it to return something (it will silently return `undefined` because there is not a `return` statement in your callback).

Comment: Callbacks aren't only for asynchronous code, they're also for higher-order functions like `.forEach()`.

Comment: @Barmar that's why I wrote "**Your** "callback" has **little** or no sense"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In my "real" application, the main function is connecting to a database, running SQL, getting the result set and then I am sending the result back using the callback. It all works well until I added the 2nd function and saw the error in the catch block. Then I was confused but I understand the call-stack now.

Answer (score 0):

That's how exception handling works. The error is thrown inside `myFunc2`, and isn't caught there - so it travels up the call stack. Since `myFunc2` was called from within a `try` block in `myFunc1`, the `catch` clause there is executed. Any exception can be caught anywhere in the call-stack above the point where it actually occurred (the first such point, travelling up from the point where the exception occurs, really does "catch" it and therefore stops the propagation). Only if we reach the global scope, at the top of the stack, is the error actually printed to the console and execution terminated, if it isn't caught there.

Also, I note you say that "I thought the first function was finished after the callback". This clearly isn't the case. The first function ends after its `return` statement, but since you return the return value of the callback, it doesn't finish until the callback has.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I now understand your explanation of traveling up the call-stack and finding a try/catch block to catch the error. Can you clarify your statement where you say that I "return the return value of the callback"? Originally I did not have the keyword "return" in front of the callback. I think this is what you are referring to.

Comment: Actually the fact you `return` the callback's return value isn't relevant to that point. The point is that the function still hadn't finished, because `myFunc2` hadn't yet finished when the error occurred inside it, and `myFunc1` can't finish until `myFunc2` does, because executing `myFunc2` is part of executing `myFunc1`. While it's true that a `return` statement ends a function, it also ends when it runs out of code to run (when there is an implicit `return;` or `return undefined;`).

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
return (callback(myData));
```

it doesn't return before the callback is executed. It's equivalent to:

```
let temp = callback(myData);
return temp;
```

This makes it clearer that it first calls the callback, then returns whatever the callback returned. If the callback signals an error, it will still be caught by the current function's `try/catch` block.